# How to convert object array to url string?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to generate javascript object array to urlstring like:

```
var array = [{'name': 'foo', 'value': '2'},
             {'name': 'foo', 'value': '2,8'},
             {'name': 'foo', 'value': '2,10,3'}
            ];

// url ==> foo=2&foo=2,8&foo=2,10,3
```

Comment: I believe this might be possible, with a little bit of effort. What have you tried?

Comment: I tried $.param(array) but not it is not working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this

```
var url = "";
array.forEach(function(e){
   url += e.name + "=" + e.value + "&";
});
url = url.trim("&");
```

Answer (score 9):

To be safe, you'd want to encode the component pieces:

```js
const array = [
  {'name': 'foo', 'value': '2'},
  {'name': 'foo', 'value': '2,8'},
  {'name': 'foo', 'value': '2,10,3'}
];

const parts = array.map((param) => {
  return(
    encodeURIComponent(param.name) + '=' +
    encodeURIComponent(param.value)
  );
});

const url = parts.join('&');

console.log(url);
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to loop through the array, determine whether the array entry is the first or not (so that they will be separated with ampersands, and use the JSON field names.

```
var queryString = "";
for ( var i = 0; i++; i < array.length ) {
    if ( i > 0 ) {
        queryString = queryString + "&";
    }
    queryString = queryString + array[i]["name"] + "=" + array[i]["value"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
var array = [{'name': 'foo', 'value': '2'},
             {'name': 'foo', 'value': '2,8'},
             {'name': 'foo', 'value': '2,10,3'}
            ];
var output = "";

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    output = output + array[i].name+"="+array[i].value+"&"
}

output = output.substring(0, output.length-1);
alert(output)
```

Here the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oscarvady/kyzwthL9/)

Answer (score 1):

If your array contains object with parameters 'name' and 'value', you should use:

$.param(array)

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/

Answer (score 0):

No need loops and aux vars, Array built-in methods do it.

[Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) + [Array.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```
> array.map(p => p.name + '=' + p.value).join('&')
'foo=2&foo=2,8&foo=2,10,3'

> array.map(function(param){
    return param.name + '=' + param.value
  }).join('&')
'foo=2&foo=2,8&foo=2,10,3'
```

safe use (but not expected OP's output):

```
> array.map(p => encodeURIComponent(p.name) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(p.value)).join('&')
'foo=2&foo=2%2C8&foo=2%2C10%2C3'
```